# Connecting fetchmail (or another MRA) to Exchange

Tags: software-rec, exchange, fetchmail

I currently use fetchmail as my MRA, using IMAP to connect to my office's Exchange 2007 server. Unfortunately, IT is disabling POP3 and IMAP access soon. Does fetchmail support connecting to Exchange servers directly? If not (and I'm pretty convinced the answer is no), is there another MRA that does support Exchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not currently, though there was an interest to improve Exchange support I think it stalled due to lack of involvement. The only similar tool I know of is [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) and doesn't natively support Exchange either.

The only solution I know of is [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), which provides a standard POP/IMAP/SMTP interface to Exchange. You should be able to use that in conjunction with Fetchmail.